# C++ API to extract model with textures form glb file

Tags: c++, api, 3d

I need to extract a 3d model with all coresponding textures from glb file in a format I can use in some 3d editor tools. The best format suported by many 3d editors is 3ds. A beter solution would be if it is posible to save the model in my own custom format. The textures need to be exported to any comon format for textures. Would be good if the API is crosplatform, at least it should have no OS related or other external dependancies.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: What should I limit?

Comment: @convert this is just automated message posted when the question get close votes of type "Needs more focus". As the close reason says: "This question currently includes multiple questions in one. It should focus on one problem only.". The automated comment has bad wording, that's all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[TinyGLTF](https://github.com/syoyo/tinygltf) is a header only C++11 glTF 2.0 library. This should give you access to the contents of a glb file, including textures and model. You can then export this in the format of your choice, of course you have to show yourself how to export it.

Comment: Is there some documentation of that API?

Comment: @convert Unfortunately, I couldn't find any documentation on this, so I had to explain everything using the examples available there.